# Designing an algorithm that determines if the numbers in the list are equal to a mod b

Tags: algorithms

I was doing some interview problems when I ran into an interesting one that I could not think of a solution for. The problems states:

> Design a function that takes in an array of integers. The last two numbers
>       in this array are 'a' and 'b'. The function should find if *all* of the
>       numbers in the array, when summed/subtracted in some fashion, are equal to
>       a mod b, except the last two numbers a and b.

So, for example, let us say we have an array:

```
array = [5, 4, 3, 3, 1, 3, 5].
```

I need to find out if there exists any possible "placement" of `+/-` in this array so that the numbers can equal `3 mod 5`. The function should print True for this array because `5+4-3+3-1 = 8 = 3 mod 5`.

The "obvious" and easy solution would be to try and add/subtract everything in all possible ways, but that is an egregiously time complex solution, maybe 
*O(2<sup>n</sup>)*.

Is there any way better to do this?

Edit: The question requires the function to use *all* numbers in the array, not *any*. Except, of course, the last two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sketch:

If you're doing this modulo $n=5$ (or another small number), create a series of arrays $A_{k}$ of length $n$ with the following property:

$A_k[i]=0$ if $i$ cannot be written as a sum/difference of the first $k$ integers and $A_k[i]=1$ if $i$ can be written as a sum/difference of the first $k$ integers.

It is fairly easy to update from $A_{k-1}$ to $A_k$ because if $j$ is the $k$th integer, then all you need to do is put $1$'s at $i+j$ and $i-j$ (modulo $n$) whenever $A_{k-1}[i]=1$.

You can really do this with two arrays by switching back and forth.

The trick is that you need to know if a sum is possible, not how to actually sum it.  So you don't need to know what the $+/-$'s are, only that it's possible.

In your example:

\begin{align}
A_0&=[1,0,0,0,0]\\
A_1&=[1,0,0,0,0]\\
A_2&=[0,1,0,0,1]\\
A_3&=[0,1,1,1,1]\\
A_4&=[1,1,1,1,1]\\
A_5&=[1,1,1,1,1]
\end{align}
Therefore, anything is possible modulo $5$ with the given sequence.

$A_0$ is $1$ in the $0$ spot and $0$'s elsewhere since the empty sum is possible, but nothing else.  $A_1$ has positions $0+5$ and $0-5$ turned on, but they're both $0$.  $A_2$ has positions $0+4$ and $0-4$ turned on.  $A_3$ has positions $1+3$, $1-3$, $4-3$, and $4+3$ turned on, and so on.

Comment: Can you define a "small number"?

Comment: The complexity of this algorithm will be $O(n\ell)$ where $\ell$ is the number of integers.  The arrays are going to be of length $n$.  You want these to be reasonable sizes for your computer - I would guess that if $n\ell$ is less than a million, your algorithm will be very practical.

Comment: Okay, having some trouble understanding how $A_k$ should be constructed. Can you give me an example?

Comment: (Michael explained while I was writing this.) Use your example, where $n=5$. $A_1$ tells whether using the first integer ($5$) you can get a result that is $0, 1, 2, 3, $ or $4$ modulo $5$. I’ll use $t$ and $f$ for true and false. The only possible result using just $5$ is $0$ modulo $5$, so the array $A_1$ is $(t,f,f,f,f)$. Now using two integers (the new one being $4$), we can add $4$ or subtract $4$ from any of the $t$ positions in the previous array, and we get $(f,t,f,f,t)$. Using the third integer $3$, we can go $\pm3$ from any $t$ in the previous array, to get $(f,t,t,t,t)$. And so on.

Comment: @SteveKass Thank you both, after thinking about it for like 20 minutes, I finally got it. Kinda slow with these things. You guys are awesome! Thank you!